# Issues with the CKEditor plugin AutoSave, when there is more than one editor on the same page

Tags: ckeditor, multiple-instances, coldfusion-11, autosave

I have a web page which contains 6 CKEditor instances, using the [AutoSave plugin](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/addon/autosave).

The AutoSave plugin works perfectly with single instances on a page but not with multiple instances. Multiple instances cause erratic behavior in that 6 prompts relating to autosaved content are displayed one at a time, but they are unresponsive.

I appreciate that each CKEditor instance requires a unique ID (as is illustrated in the code below) and research has shown me how to set these IDs within CKEditor.replace but for the life of me, I cannot get it to work.

I have tried different browsers and cache cleaning, to no avail.

The following code is in a loop of 6 iterations within a table. I have verified that the ColdFusion variable values are correct. The autosave_Savekey range is "autosave_2" to "autosave_7".

```
<td>
<textarea name="text_value_box#agi_array[agi][5]#" cols="78" rows="<cfif #agi_array[agi][4]# EQ "R">4<cfelse>8</cfif>" #route_form#>#getItem.text_value#</textarea>
<script type="text/javascript">
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'text_value_box#agi_array[agi][5]#',
     {
        customConfig: '#Editor.customConfig#',
        allowedContent: true,
        autosave_SaveKey: 'autosave_#agi_array[agi][5]#',
        toolbar: '#Editor.toolbar#'
        <cfif isDefined('Editor.font_names')>
        , font_names: '#Editor.font_names#'
        </cfif>
        <cfif isDefined('Editor.fontSize_sizes')>
        , fontSize_sizes: '#Editor.fontSize_sizes#'
        </cfif>
        <cfif not vIsSuperUser>
        , removePlugins: 'elementspath'
        </cfif>
     }
    );
</script>
</td>
```

I would be grateful for any suggestions as to a resolution.

**Tech Spec**: 
CKEditor version: 4.9.2.
AutoSave Version: 0.1.8.
ColdFusion Version: 11.
Browsers Tested: Firefox, IE and Chrome.

Comment: I just tried changing the autosave_SaveKey assignment to "text_value_box#agi_array[agi][5]#", but that didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

**[RESOLVED]**

The correct format is:

```
<td>
    <textarea name="text_value_box#agi_array[agi][5]#" cols="78" rows="<cfif #agi_array[agi][4]# EQ "R">4<cfelse>8</cfif>" #route_form#>#getItem.text_value#</textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace( 'text_value_box#agi_array[agi][5]#', 
        {
            autosave:   
                        {
                            SaveKey: 'autosave_#agi_array[agi][5]#'
                        },           
            customConfig: '#Editor.customConfig#',
            allowedContent: true,
            toolbar: '#Editor.toolbar#'
            <cfif isDefined('Editor.font_names')>
            , font_names: '#Editor.font_names#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif isDefined('Editor.fontSize_sizes')>
            , fontSize_sizes: '#Editor.fontSize_sizes#'
            </cfif>
            <cfif not vIsSuperUser>
            , removePlugins: 'elementspath'
            </cfif>
         }
        );
    </script>
</td>
```

The documentation for the AutoSave plugin, could be a little clearer in this respect.

Thanks to [w8tcha](https://github.com/w8tcha) on [GitHub](https://github.com/) for this resolution.